Flutter Web how to give location permission
I am following this tutorial. The app uses the geolocator and geocoding packages to fetch the user's current location and display the weather for that location. The tutorial I followed showed only how to do it on Android and iOS, but it did not provide any information on how to do it on the Web Browser (Flutter Web):

Android android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 


iOS: ios/Runner/Info.plist:
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string> 



Additionally, I install the following dependencies:
//flutter pub add http
// flutter pub add geolocator
// flutter pub add geocoding
// flutter pub add lottie

Here’s a snippet of my code that fetches the weather based on the user’s current location:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/models/weather_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//TODO:
// replace desiredAccuracy:

class WeatherService {
  static const BASE_URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  final String apiKey;

  WeatherService(this.apiKey);

  Future<Weather> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('$BASE_URL?q=$cityName&appid=$apiKey&units=metric'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Weather.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load weather data');
    }
  }

  Future<String> getCurrentCity() async {
    // get permission from user
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    }

    // fetch the current location
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    // convert the location into a list of placemark objects
    List<Placemark> placemarks =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    // extract the city name from the first placemark
    String? city = placemarks[0].locality;
    return city ?? "";
  }
}

How do you properly set location permissions for the Web?

"I have successfully set up the location permissions" VS "How do you properly set location permissions for the Web?" - Please clarify the problem you are experiencing. What is not working? Are you receiving any errors? [ask]

The tutorial I followed showed only how to do it on Android and iOS. For both of them, I added, but unfortunately, the tutorial did not provide any information on how to do it on the Web.

What does for the web mean? You mean browser?

Sorry, yes for the web browser.
